# HTML doesn't fit text that there is space for

Tags: html, css

This is the layout that I want to achieve
[image]

But for some reason when I add the paragraph right next to the picture, it breaks the whole div, and I'm left with this:
[image]
Also, you can see that instead of overflowing, it tries to concatenate it. It even adds a ruler at the bottom.
This is my code:

```html
<htmL>
 <head>
  <title>Ohrid</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
  <h1 style="color: #00dd00">Ohridsko Ezero</h1>
  <hr style="background-color: #0d0; height:2px; border: none;">
  <div>
   <div style="display: inline-block;  ">
    <img src="./images/karta_small.jpg" width="180" height="280" border="0" hspace="60" style="display:inline-block; word-break: break-all">
   </div>
   <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Osnovni geografski i hidrografski karakteristiki</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Zivotinski i rastitelen svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Riben Svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Karakteristiki na nekoi vidovi ribi</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="./images/logo.gif" width="50px;" height="25px;" style="display: inline-block">
     <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ohridsko+Ezero&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=" target="_new">Prebaraj na Google za Ohridskoto Ezero</a>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- imagine this is the paragraph -->
     asdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdas
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</htmL>
```

Let me note that there is enough space to fit the text, it just breaks the moment it reaches the end of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to solve this probplem. Just add 'display: flex;' property to the container element:

```html
<htmL>
 <head>
  <title>Ohrid</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
  <h1 style="color: #00dd00">Ohridsko Ezero</h1>
  <hr style="background-color: #0d0; height:2px; border: none;">
  <div style="display: flex;">
   <div style="display: inline-block;  ">
    <img src="./images/karta_small.jpg" width="180" height="280" border="0" hspace="60" style="display:inline-block; word-break: break-all">
   </div>
   <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Osnovni geografski i hidrografski karakteristiki</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Zivotinski i rastitelen svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Riben Svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Karakteristiki na nekoi vidovi ribi</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="./images/logo.gif" width="50px;" height="25px;" style="display: inline-block">
     <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ohridsko+Ezero&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=" target="_new">Prebaraj na Google za Ohridskoto Ezero</a>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- imagine this is the paragraph -->
     asdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdas
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</htmL>
```

Comment: bless you, happy holidays

Comment: glad to help u ;)

Answer (score 1):

For long paragraph issue:

Add `word-break:break-all` style inline `body` tag.

```html
<htmL>
  <head>
    <title>Ohrid</title>
  </head>
  <body style="word-break:break-all; background-color:#f1f1f1">
  <h1 style="color: #00dd00">Ohridsko Ezero</h1>
  <hr style="background-color: #0d0; height:2px; border: none;">
  <div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;  ">
      <img src="./images/karta_small.jpg" width="180" height="280" border="0" hspace="60" style="display:inline-block; word-break: break-all">
    </div>
   <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Osnovni geografski i hidrografski karakteristiki</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Zivotinski i rastitelen svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Riben Svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Karakteristiki na nekoi vidovi ribi</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="./images/logo.gif" width="50px;" height="25px;" style="display: inline-block">
     <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ohridsko+Ezero&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=" target="_new">Prebaraj na Google za Ohridskoto Ezero</a>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div>
     <!-- imagine this is the paragraph -->
     asdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdas
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</htmL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, you want the text to overflow to the next line instead of creating a horizontal scrollbar?

For this you'll need to give the div a defined width and add `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
#overflow{
    width:100vw;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

```html
    <htmL>
     <head>
      <title>Ohrid</title>
     </head>
     <body style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
      <h1 style="color: #00dd00">Ohridsko Ezero</h1>
      <hr style="background-color: #0d0; height:2px; border: none;">
      <div>
       <div style="display: inline-block;  ">
        <img src="./images/karta_small.jpg" width="180" height="280" border="0" hspace="60" style="display:inline-block; word-break: break-all">
       </div>
       <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top">
        <div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
         <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Osnovni geografski i hidrografski karakteristiki</h2></a>
         <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Zivotinski i rastitelen svet</h2></a>
         <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Riben Svet</h2></a>
         <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Karakteristiki na nekoi vidovi ribi</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div>
         <img src="./images/logo.gif" width="50px;" height="25px;" style="display: inline-block">
         <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ohridsko+Ezero&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=" target="_new">Prebaraj na Google za Ohridskoto Ezero</a>
         </span>
        </div>
        <div id="overflow">
         <!-- imagine this is the paragraph -->
         asdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdas
        </div>
       </div> 
      </div>
     </body>
    </htmL>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to add text next to an image: just put them in the same div, and add the style `float: left;` to the image, like this:

```html
<htmL>
 <head>
  <title>Ohrid</title>
 </head>
 <body style="background-color: #f1f1f1">
  <h1 style="color: #00dd00">Ohridsko Ezero</h1>
  <hr style="background-color: #0d0; height:2px; border: none;">
  <div>
   <div>
    <img src="./images/karta_small.jpg" width="180" height="280" hspace="60" style="float: left;">
    <div style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Tahoma">
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Osnovni geografski i hidrografski karakteristiki</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Zivotinski i rastitelen svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Riben Svet</h2></a>
     <a href="#" style="color: #77ee00"><h2 style="margin: 0">Karakteristiki na nekoi vidovi ribi</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div>
     <img src="./images/logo.gif" width="50px;" height="25px;" style="display: inline-block">
     <span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align: top">
      <a href="https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Ohridsko+Ezero&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=" target="_new">Prebaraj na Google za Ohridskoto Ezero</a>
     </span>
    </div>
    <div style='word-break: break-word;'>
     <!-- imagine this is the paragraph -->
     asdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdasasdasdasdsdaasdasdadsadsadsdas
    </div>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </body>
</htmL>
```

To wrap the single word paragraph to the next line, add `style='word-break: break-word;'` to the div that contains it.